# Pre-selection of data for migration to the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Is there any way in Django to populate the database with multiple records during the migration, or after it, except for the manual method, or restore the backup.

For example:
I have a model with services, which after the creation of the database should already have 3 entries, because it is a binder.

How do I implement this in Django 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From django documentation on [Data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

> Django can’t automatically generate data migrations for you, as it
>   does with schema migrations, but it’s not very hard to write them.
>   Migration files in Django are made up of Operations, and the main
>   operation you use for data migrations is RunPython.

Example

```
 from django.db import migrations

 def combine_names(apps, schema_editor):
     # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
     # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
     Person = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Person')
     for person in Person.objects.all():
         person.name = '%s %s' % (person.first_name, person.last_name)
         person.save()

 class Migration(migrations.Migration):

     dependencies = [
         ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
     ]

     operations = [
         migrations.RunPython(combine_names),
     ]
```